# Как положить несколько классов в массив и вывести их через цикл?

Tags: python

Не могу понять как положить все данные в классе в массив и вывести их через цикл.
Делаю вот так, но ошибка. Подскажите пожалуйста. Нужно film_1 И film_2 положить в массив self.base и потом вывести его через цикл. Не дойдет до меня никак(

```
class Cinima:
    
    def __init__(self,film_name,director,first_year):
        self.base = []
        self.film_name = film_name
        self.director = director
        self.first_year = first_year


    def get_info(self):
        print(self.film_name)
        print(self.director)
        print(self.first_year)

    def add_films_for_base(self):
        self.base.append(film_1, film_2)



    def get_info_all(self):
        for i in self.base:
            print(i)



film_1 = Cinima('НЕПРОЩЕННЫЙ', 'Сарик Андреасян', 2018 )
film_2 = Cinima('исходный код', 'Данкан Джонс', 2011 )

Cinima.get_info_all()
```

Comment: Вам предоставили несколько решений. Выберите пожалуйста одно решение, которое подходит вам и отметьте его как правильное, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если чуть модифицировать код @CrazyElf:

```
class Cinima:
    films_list = []

    def __init__(self,film_name,director,first_year):
        self.film_name = film_name
        self.director = director
        self.first_year = first_year

        Cinima.films_list.append(self)

    def get_info_all():
        for i in Cinima.films_list:
            print(i)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Название: {self.film_name}, Режиссёр: {self.director}, Год: {self.first_year}'

Cinima('НЕПРОЩЕННЫЙ', 'Сарик Андреасян', 2018)
Cinima('исходный код', 'Данкан Джонс', 2011)

Cinima.get_info_all()
```

Причем можно сделать `films_list` скрытым, чтобы напрямую извне к нему нельзя было получить доступ:

для этого член класса надо назвать через двойное подчеркивание `__имя`

```
class Cinima:
    __films_list = []

    def __init__(self,film_name, director, first_year):
        self.film_name = film_name
        self.director = director
        self.first_year = first_year

        Cinima.__films_list.append(self)

    def get_info_all():
        for i in Cinima.__films_list:
            print(i)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Название: {self.film_name}, Режиссёр: {self.director}, Год: {self.first_year}'

Cinima('НЕПРОЩЕННЫЙ', 'Сарик Андреасян', 2018 )
Cinima('исходный код', 'Данкан Джонс', 2011)

# сработает
Cinima.get_info_all()

# не сработает
print(*Cinima.__films_list, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Cinima.__films_list.append(self)  - не мог бы ты подробнее написать почему мы именно так добавляем, и зачем в конце self? Не понимаю..

Comment: мы добавляем в список `__films_list` экземпляр класса, чтобы потом можно было вызывать из списка методы класса, которые будут работать с данными экземпляра класса, ничто не мешает передавать только данные, например `Cinima.__films_list.append((film_name, director, first_year))`, но мы их зачем-то присваиваем членам класса `self.film_name` и т.д., поэтому лучше передать сразу экземпляр класса, а `self` -это как бы указатель экземпляра класса на самого себя, поэтому его и используем

Comment: воу, теперь все ясно! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Ну как-то так:

```
class Cinima:
    films_list = []        

    def __init__(self,film_name,director,first_year):
        self.film_name = film_name
        self.director = director
        self.first_year = first_year


    def get_info(self):
        print(self.film_name)
        print(self.director)
        print(self.first_year)

    def add_films(films):
        for film in films:
            Cinima.films_list.append(film)

    def get_info_all():
        for i in Cinima.films_list:
            print(i)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Название: {self.film_name}, Режиссёр: {self.director}, Год: {self.first_year}'

Cinima.add_films([Cinima('НЕПРОЩЕННЫЙ', 'Сарик Андреасян', 2018 ), Cinima('исходный код', 'Данкан Джонс', 2011)])
Cinima.get_info_all()
```

Вам просто надо разобраться, что какие переменные должны быть **переменными экземпляра класса**, а какие **переменными самого класса**. Список фильмов, конечно, должен быть переменной не экземпляра (представляющего конкретный фильм), а всего класса.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
class Cinima:
    def __init__(self, film_name, director, first_year):
        self.film_name = film_name
        self.director = director
        self.first_year = first_year

    def get_info(self):
        print(self.film_name)
        print(self.director)
        print(self.first_year)


class InfoAll:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.base = []
        self.film_1 = Cinima('НЕПРОЩЕННЫЙ', 'Сарик Андреасян', 2018 )
        self.base.append(self.film_1)
        self.film_2 = Cinima('исходный код', 'Данкан Джонс', 2011 )
        self.base.append(self.film_2)

    def get_info_all(self):
        for i in self.base:
            print(i.film_name, i.director, i.first_year,)


info_all = InfoAll()
info_all.get_info_all()
```

Comment: какой я тупой.. Спасибо всем!